how can set bootstrap 4 date picker formatting day-month-years
i use bootstrap 4 datepicker . but datepicker date formate is month-days-years.
I am trying to set up a date picker using Bootstrap 4, and I need the date format to be displayed as day-month-year (dd-mm-yyyy).
Can someone please provide me with a step-by-step guide or code example on how to format the date picker to display dates in the format dd-mm-yyyy?
Thank you.
